# How to change pagination position in table to center using antd for angular?

Tags: angular, antd

I am on Antd vs.12.0.2 and I tried to implement datatable using Angular and Antd for Angular.

This is my nz-table code content.

```
  <nz-table
    #membersTable
    nz-show-pagination
    nzSize="default"
    nzTableLayout="fixed"
    nzPaginationType="default"
    nzPaginationPosition="bottom"
    [nzData]="members"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th>Accounts</th>
        <th nzWidth="70px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let member of membersTable.data">
        <tr class="org-admin-member-row" [member]="member"></tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </nz-table>
```

There wasn't a property to move pagination to center in table. So, I tried to override styles but nothing changed.

Here's what I tried in less file.

```
nz-table {
  nz-pagination {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Isn't it possible to override antd class styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found an answer to solve this problem. To help the others who will run into the same problem with me, I am going to publish this answer to public.

Angular prefixes its styles which are used for component by its component id like this.

```
.header[_ngcontent-jjj-c93]   .user-dropdown[_ngcontent-jjj-c93] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content[_ngcontent-jjj-c93] {
  background-color: white;
}
.bottom-menu[_ngcontent-jjj-c93] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

So, when I tried to override styles, they were prefixed like this.

```
nz-table[_ngcontent-jjj-c198] nz-pagination[_ngcontent-jjj-c198] {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This was why overriding styles couldn't change pagination position, so I created overriding styles inside the custom.less file, which is inside src/app/styles folder and used for defining custom global styles inside the application.

The code is like below.

```
org-admin-members {
  .ant-table-pagination {
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
}
```

It changed pagination position successfully.

Note: You have to ensure that you included custom.less file in src/app/styles.less file and you should add '!important' rule to css style.